# iOS and Windows reports "No Internet Connection" for Wi-fi with same SSID

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, ios

I have a router R, a Wifi extender E1 broadcasting R, and another extender E2 broadcasting E1, and they all share the same SSID, security method and password. I have an iOS 10, a Windows 10 and a macOS all connected to E2.

The problem is that iOS and Windows frequently report "No Internet Connection", but macOS has a very stable connection, which proves that R, E1 and E2 all have connection to the Internet (They can all connected to the Internet through E1 though).

Is there any way to fix this problem?

My guess is:

1. macOS stores the Wifi by MAC address, but iOS and Windows store them by SSID. There are some conflicting information for these access points, which cause the system to refuse to connect. Then what information except for SSID, security method and password may have caused this issue?
2. Unix (macOS) has some tools to help configuring multiple Wifi with the same SSID. Then is there any alternatives for iOS and Windows to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit by increasing the Roaming Aggressiveness of your wireless adapters.  It doesn't always work (my home Windows 10 device ignores Roaming Aggressiveness setting and needs to be toggled on/off in order to connect to the nearest node on my extended wifi network).